# Conexão ssh entre computadores

Tags: linux, shell-script

Como fazer uma conexão via `ssh` entre um pc local e um servidor, com método de autenticado por chaves.

Comment: Sua pergunta é muito ampla, dê uma olhada aqui: https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Acesso-SSH

Answer (score 1):

Dentre as opções dê uma olhada nesses posts:

[SSH Autentication](http://blogdonerd.com.br/2012/05/autenticacao-ssh-utilizando-certificado-digital-em-smart-card/)

[Autenticação por chave](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/SSH-com-chave-de-autenticacao-publica)